# Como obtener los puntos(i,j) de una matriz rde recorrido mas corto

Tags: java

/**hola,buenas llego atascado en este problema hace dias, practicamente debo de hallar el camino mas corto de *un punto (i,j) a otro (i,j) pero lo que nesecito no es el numero de casillas recorridas si no que todos lo *puntos (i,j).Lo nesecito para graficar ..Entremos en contexto,esta es una aplicacion de un botoon de panico *que una veez es presionado,este debe de informar a una central la cual informara ya sea ala policia,hospital , *y le dara una ruta mas corta ,tambien trate de implementarlo con el algoritmo de dijkstra pero no se como *identificar las aristas y vertices .Practicamente estoy con esas dos soluciones pero ninguna la puedo *impplemtar, agradeceria sus ayuda . Les adjunto el codigo que me devuelve el camino mas corto.

/*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mapa {
    private String name;
    private int tamanio;
    private int cantBotones;
    private UbicacionBoton ubiPolicia;//solo son ubicacionEnELPlano.Uno x,y
    private UbicacionBoton ubiHospital;
    private UbicacionBoton ubiBomberos;
    private ArrayList<Boton>botones;

    private int [][]mapa;


    public Mapa(String name,int mapa[][],int tamanio,UbicacionBoton ubiBomberos,
                UbicacionBoton ubiHospital,UbicacionBoton ubiPolicia){
        this.name=name;
        this.tamanio=tamanio;
        mapa=new int[tamanio][tamanio];//sePodriaConsiderarElTam
        this.ubiBomberos=ubiBomberos;
        this.ubiHospital=ubiHospital;
        this.ubiPolicia=ubiPolicia;
        cantBotones=tamanio*tamanio/6;//para que tengan un numero limitado de botones
        this.mapa=mapa;
        botones=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private int xFin;
    private int yFin;
    public Mapa(int tamanio){
        this.tamanio=tamanio;
    }
    //podria devolver un conjunto de puntos para elCamino mas corto
    public int caminoMasCorto(UbicacionBoton ini,UbicacionBoton fin){
      int xIni=ini.getLatitud();
      int yIni=ini.getLongitud();
      xFin=fin.getLatitud();
      yFin=fin.getLongitud();
      ArrayList<Par>par=new ArrayList<>();
      int disMin=caminoMasCorto(xIni,yIni,xFin,yFin,0,par);
      aBus=disMin;
      return disMin;
    }

    private boolean valida(int x, int y){
        return x>=0 && x<tamanio && y>=0 && y<tamanio;
    }

    private boolean estaQ(int x, int y,int xFin,int yFin){
        return x==xFin && y==yFin;
    }

    private int min(int v1, int v2){
        int min;
        if(v1 == -1)
            min = v2;
        else
        if(v2 == -1)
            min = v1;
        else
        if(v1 < v2)
            min = v1;
        else
            min = v2;
        return min;
    }

    public int caminoMasCorto(int xini,int yini,int xFin, int yFin,int distMin
                            ,ArrayList<Par>par){
        if(valida(xini,yini)){
           // Par parcito=new Par(xini,yini);
            //paress.add(parcito);
            if(estaQ(xini,yini,xFin,yFin)){
                distMin = 0;

            }else{
                if(mapa[xini][yini] ==-1){//casas
                    distMin = -1;
                   // pares.add(paress);
                    //paress.remove(paress.size()-1);
                    //ArrayList<Par>pa=new ArrayList<>(paress);
                    //paress.removeAll(paress);
                    //paress=pa;

                }else{
                    if(mapa[xini][yini] == -2){//senial
                        distMin = -1;


                    }else{

                        mapa[xini][yini] = -2;//senial

                        distMin = caminoMasCorto(xini-1,yini,xFin,yFin,distMin,par);
                        distMin = min(distMin, caminoMasCorto(xini, yini+1,xFin,yFin,distMin,par));
                        distMin = min(distMin, caminoMasCorto(xini+1,yini,xFin,yFin,distMin,par));
                        distMin = min(distMin, caminoMasCorto(xini, yini-1,xFin,yFin,distMin,par));
                        if(distMin > -1){
                            distMin ++;
                        }
                        mapa[xini][yini] = -2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            distMin = -1;
        }
        return distMin;
    }
/**
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Par>>pares=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Par>paress=new ArrayList<>();
    private int aBus;
    public ArrayList<Par>darPares(){
        ArrayList<Par>res=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<pares.size();i++){
            if(pares.get(i).size()!=aBus){
                pares.remove(i);
            }

        }

        for(int j=0;j<pares.size();j++){
            if(pares.get(j).get(paress.size()-1).getX()==xFin&&pares.get(j).get(paress.size()-1).getY()==yFin){
                res=pares.get(j);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
/*

    public boolean agregarBton(Boton b){
        if(botones.size()<cantBotones){
            botones.add(b);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;``
        }
    }
    //solo por pruebas
    public void setMapa(int [][]mapa){
        this.mapa=mapa;
    }
    public UbicacionBoton getUbiPolicia(){
        return ubiPolicia;
    }
    public UbicacionBoton getUbiHospital(){
        return ubiHospital;
    }
    public UbicacionBoton getUbiBomberos(){
        return ubiBomberos;
    }


}
```

//el codigo comentado es la forma pobre en que trate de sacar los puntos, intente mas cosas pero al final me //rendi y deje esta ultima.. GRACIAS!!